# Joint distributions and Function of a random variable

Tags: probability, distributions

In a probability distribution, is it true that $XX$ is NOT $X^2$. That is, $XX$ is a joint distribution of $X$ and $X$ and $X^2$ is a function of $X$?

Comment: To falsify the equation "$XX=X^2$", you would have to exhibit a real number $x$ (namely, a possible value of $X$) which does not satisfy the equation.  Obviously you cannot.

Comment: Let X=2, 3, 5 with Probabilities 0.2, 0.7 and 0.1 respectively. Determine E(X^2). Then form the dist XX (the product of two random variables) and let the events be independent. Determine E(XX). What do you notice?

Comment: I notice that your comment appears to have no bearing on your question.  What are you trying to ask about?  Could you define your notation or try to restate it in words?

Comment: Basically I'm asking is it true that E(X^2) is NOT E(XX)? I believe the situation I have stated earlier supports this. Do you agree or not, why? In other words try what I have asked above.

Comment: Otherwise, just forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a notation problem: what does $XX$ represent? Note $XX$ is not a widely used notation.

Are you trying to use $XX$ to represent $2$ outcomes from two random events? or Are you tying to use $XX$ to represent a product of two random variables.

If $XX$ represents $2$ outcomes, then the distribution can be described with joint distribution. But most people will use a different notation, where $X_1X_2$ are used. For example, in a coin flip, people will use $P(X_1=H, X_2=H)$ to represent $2$ head flip.

On the other hand, if you use $XX$ to represent a product of two random variables, the distribution of the new random variable is $X^2$.

Comment: Yes I want XX to represent a product of two random variables. Then is it true that E(XX) is NOT E(X^2)? And wouldn't this then imply XX is NOT X^2?

Comment: I think if you have two random variables $X$ and $X$ and they are independent and identical, then, $E(XX)=E(X^2)$.

Comment: Let X=2, 3, 5 with Probabilities 0.2, 0.7 and 0.1 respectively. Determine E(X^2). Then form the dist XX (the product of two random variables) and let the events be independent. Determine E(XX). What do you notice?

Comment: $X^2$ will be 4, 9, 25, with prob. 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, $E(X^2)=4*0.2+9*0.7+25*0.1$